# How to Add Row in datagrid wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, datagrid

```
  Private Property DataTable As DataTable
    Public Property DataView As DataView
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    DataTable = New DataTable()
    DataTable.Columns.Add("Test")
    DataView = DataTable.DefaultView
    DataContext = Me
    Dim dr As DataRow = DataTable.NewRow()
    dr("Test") = "Wert1"
    DataTable.Rows.Add(dr)
End Sub
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataView}"/>
```

Above this code working properly. But when I am substitute into my code **dr** is showing error message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgQcs.jpg)

below is my code

```
Private Property DataTable As DataTable
Public Property DataView As New DataView
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    InitializeComponent()
    Dim startDate As Date = CType(dtpStartDate.SelectedDate, DateTime)
    Dim endDate As Date = CType(dtpEndDate.SelectedDate, DateTime)
    While startDate <= endDate
        Dim NewColumn As New DataGridTextColumn()
        NewColumn.Header = startDate.ToShortDateString()
        dgTemplate.Columns.Add(NewColumn)
        startDate = startDate.AddDays(1)
        DataView = DataTable.DefaultView
        DataContext = Me
        Dim dr As DataRow = DataTable.NewRow()
        dr(NewColumn) = "Wert1"
        DataTable.Rows.Add(dr)
    End While
End Sub
```

can anyone suggest to fix this...

Answer (score 0):

Datarow constructor cant take column object as an argument.

Use column.header property to specify column.

```
Private Property DataTable As DataTable
Public Property DataView As New DataView
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    InitializeComponent()
    Dim startDate As Date = CType(dtpStartDate.SelectedDate, DateTime)
    Dim endDate As Date = CType(dtpEndDate.SelectedDate, DateTime)
    While startDate <= endDate
        Dim NewColumn As New DataGridTextColumn()
        NewColumn.Header = startDate.ToShortDateString()
        dgTemplate.Columns.Add(NewColumn)
        startDate = startDate.AddDays(1)
        DataView = DataTable.DefaultView
        DataContext = Me
        Dim dr As DataRow = DataTable.NewRow()
        dr(NewColumn.Header) = "Wert1" '<----------------------------
        DataTable.Rows.Add(dr)
    End While
End Sub
```

Info
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.-ctor?view=net-6.0